# I need help about forms in Angular

Tags: angular, forms

I try to add a form to a component page, and I want to add some control on the date format which has to be done when the user clicks on the `submit` button. I am using `ReactiveFormsModule`.

But the following code does nothing.  It compiles but still the form is submitted even when the date format does not match de regular expression in its FormControl.

What did I miss?

Please note that I'm a beginner in Angular and this is my first form.

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formulaireRechercheDeCohorte" (ngSubmit)="rechercheCohorte()">

<label for="jour-debut-cohorte" class="sr-only">Jour du début</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="jour-debut-cohorte" 
name="periodeDebut" 
[(ngModel)]="criteresRechercheCohorte.datePeriodeDebut"
 formControlName="controleurDateDebutPeriode" />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>

</form>
```

Controler:

```
formulaireRechercheDeCohorte: FormGroup;
  controleurDateDebutPeriode: FormControl;

  constructor() {
    this.controleurDateDebutPeriode = new FormControl(Validators.pattern(/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/));
    this.formulaireRechercheDeCohorte = new FormGroup({
      "controleurDateDebutPeriode" : this.controleurDateDebutPeriode
    });
  }

rechercheCohorte() {
...call to http service
}
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to post a stringified version of the date format you want vs what you are receiving? I'm not familiar with regex. However, I'd like to help you if I can.

Comment: If you use formGroup -ReactiveForm NOT use [(ngModel)]. new FormControl(..) is new FormControl(value,Validators), -you are given Validators as value-

Comment: But how can I bind the <input> to the model if I don't use ngModel?

Comment: @fruustyl3r, using formControlName, as you write, but remove [(ngModel)]. If you want to give value to the formControl, you can use new FormControl("your-value",...). I think that in the official docs https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms is good explain :(

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll keep the offical docs link in my favs now :)

Answer (score 0):

See this working [StackBlitz of your example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-weczek)

You need to update your `FormControl` to include a value like this `this.controleurDateDebutPeriode = new FormControl('' , Validators.pattern(/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}$/));`

Also you can add the `disabled` attribute to your submit button to prevent the user from submitting an invalid form in the first place like so.

`<button type="submit" [disabled]="!formulaireRechercheDeCohorte.valid" lass="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>`

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been able to add my control. I have an additionnal question: is it possible to do the form validation on submit only without adding a boolean like "formIsSubmitted"?